# Jump to matplotlib axes object based on axes label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In matplotlib it is possible to pass a figure name to a newly created figure:

`plt.figure('figure1')`

This is extremely handy when trying to make a previously created figure current, for example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure('figure1')
plt.figure('figure2')
plt.figure('figure1')
```

The fourth line in the above script will go back to the figure created in the second line without necessarily adding a new figure.

Similarly, it is possible to add an axes to a figure along with a label for the axes. The following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure('figure1')
rect1 = (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
rect2 = (0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
fig.add_axes(rect1, label = 'axes1')
fig.add_axes(rect2, label = 'axes2')
```

Adds axes objects with labels 'axes1' and 'axes2' to the current figure. I would like to know if it is possible to refer back to these axes along the same lines as jumping back to a figure based on it's label. something like

```
ax = plt.axes('axes2')
```

such that later on I can plot a set of data specifically to my axis of choice, but based on the label of the axis.

```
ax.plot(XData, YData)
```

I need to do this because all my data is part of a dictionary which I am designing to be figure and axes-aware. That is the keys in the key-value pairs should become the figure and axis labels. Further more I am plotting several things on each axis, but not at the same time in my loop.

Any ideas on whether this is possible?

Comment: i would store all of these things in a dictionary so that you can refer them by keys

Comment: the dictionary's sole purpose is to store the raw data in a tree structure. It needs to be outside the function. The function I'd like to generate would have the following form: `def AddXYDataToSubPlot(XData, YData, FigureName, AxesName, LineName):` where `XData` and `YData` are arrays

Comment: Do you know the number of axes before you start the plotting routine?

Comment: Nope. But I do know the algorithm that determines where the new axes needs to get added positionwise on my figure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function to get an axes from its label. But you can write one yourself. Loop over all axes in a figure and return the axes with the desired label.

```
def get_ax_by_name(fig, name):
    for axi in fig.axes:
        label = axi.get_label()
        if label == name:
            return axi
    return plt.gca()

def func(x,y, figure_name, axes_name):
    fig = plt.figure(figure_name)
    ax = get_ax_by_name(fig, axes_name)
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: I don't really like to write my own functions for this type of stuff, but I guess its the only option in this case. Thanks very much

Comment: Apparently you are writing you complete own framework to plot things so an additional function like this would not hurt.

Comment: One follow up question, why are you returning the plt.gca()? Is this sort of a default value? meaning if it can't find the label to just return the current axes? I'm a bit confused about that last line in `get_ax_by_name`

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am returning the current axes in case none of the axes matches the name to ensure that an axes is indeed returned.